# Can workmen legally restrict access to my property?

Tags: property

So I got this note through the door....
[image: Letter I recieved]

Is this legal?
I need access in and out of my flat at all times...
It's also the only way in and out - so it's our fire exit.

Any advice would be amazing :)

Comment: They apparently misspelled "upgrading" as "ugrading"

Comment: Making ingress/egress somewhat more difficult is not the same as totally blocking it, though it may be briefly completely blocked for a period of hours (I know from experience).

Comment: Are they actually talking about a road? If so, worrying about a fire exit makes no sense.

Comment: @Nij - it's essentially a tunnel between two buildings with my flat above it. My flat's only way in or out is my front door which is half way down the tunnel... And they're going to be resurfacing that tunnel - so while they do Im blocked in or out my flat

Comment: If the only entrance/exit to your living quarters is in a tunnel, you already have far more significant problems, and this incident is just a minor demonstration of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a tenant (renter), then it is very likely that your rental agreement states something like, the Management/owners can make reasonable restrictions for purposes of maintenance.

Whether 8 or 9 days can be considered "reasonable" is a subject of debate, and you may be able to negotiate with your landlord on this point, possibly for discounted rent or other accommodation.

---

If you are the owner, then it is unclear from your question who exactly is restricting access:  A neighboring property? the local city?

Comment: I am a renter, but it's not this properties management doing the work - it's a neighbour...